# Как правильно вывести текст на экран Windows form?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно передать из поля ввода текст, который был введен пользователем, в поле вывода текста выше?

вот как выглядит модель  интерфейса

[image: модель формы программы]

В качестве поле ввода я использовал **Rich TextBox** и полсе нажатия button Сказать, текст должен отформатироваться моим кодом и попасть в поле вывода текста.
В качестве вывода введенного текста использовал **List View**

Текст должен выводится, не стирая предыдущий текст т.е. старый текст прокручивается автоматически вверх или в низ, а новый(который был повторно введен в поле ввода) отображается на экране

как правильно без ошибок получить текст из поля ввода, для отформатирования его моим кодом и затем вывести такой текст в поле вывода?

вот исходный код

```
#pragma once

namespace form {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Сводка для Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListView^  listView1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^  richTextBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Требуется переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
    /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->listView1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->richTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this->listView1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(201, -1);
        this->listView1->Name = L"listView1";
        this->listView1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(417, 309);
        this->listView1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->listView1->UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(-2, -1);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(197, 448);
        this->pictureBox1->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::StretchImage;
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this->richTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(201, 314);
        this->richTextBox1->Name = L"richTextBox1";
        this->richTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(417, 99);
        this->richTextBox1->TabIndex = 2;
        this->richTextBox1->Text = L"";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(201, 420);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(417, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button1->Text = L"Сказать";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(622, 447);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->richTextBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->listView1);
        this->MaximizeBox = false;
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^  >(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);

    }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
         {  

         }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен метод [*ListView.Items.Add*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttzhk9y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Нужно передать ему значение из текстбокса:

```
this->listView1.Add(this->richTextBox1->Text);
```

Comment: спс, за подсказку, но видимо я не совсем еще понимаю структуру формы. Как получить текст из Rich TextBox при клике мышкой? и оправить его в List View.     покажите пример  если не трудно.                                                                                                                                                                                           private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    
     this->listView1.Add(this->richTextBox1->Text);}
    

    }

Comment: @Антон, а при чем тут структура формы?

Comment: извиняюсь, в смысле не понял как надо использовать функции форм

Comment: @Антон, рассматривайте форму как обычный класс, контролы на форме - это поля этого класса - и все становится понятно, как мне кажется